# Is a nonconstant morphism of projective varieties necessarily finite?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes, projective-varieties

Let $k$ be a field, and let $X$ and $Y$ be projective varieties over $k$.

Do there exist morphisms $X \to Y$ that are neither finite nor constant? I know this cannot happen for $X$ and $Y$ curves (as nonconstant implies finite in this case), but I don't seem to find an example in the general case.

Comment: Take your favorite projective variety $Z$ distinct from a point and consider the projection $Z\times Y \to Y$. There are plenty of other examples, too - if you have more conditions, I would suggest adding to your post.

Comment: @KReiser What if $Z$ is a point, i.e. what if we restrict to endomorphisms of $Y$?

Comment: If you want to make your question more specific, I would suggest adding to it via an [edit], especially if there's something you're trying to solve here that you're not informing us about yet. (If $Y=Y_1\times Y_2$, you can get the same thing again by taking a projection and an inclusion.)

Comment: Dear Mathfan24, I often find it helpful in situations like this to apply some 'test logic': if all non-constant maps were finite, there probably wouldn't be a phrase 'finite'. Of course, you still need to find an actual example (a great example supplied by **KReiser** above), but removing the psychological barrier of 'do I expect it to be true?' is big. And, again, test logic dictates the answer to your question is no: not all non-constant maps are finite.